# 'Exit Sub' on DialogResult.OK button

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a `VB.NET` form (`CopyScenarioForm`) with a OK button (`DialogResult property = OK` ) and also assigned it as `Accept Button` for the Form.

I show this form from my main Form (`mainForm`) using

```
If DialogResult.OK = CopyScenarioForm.ShowDialog() Then
      DoSomething()
End if
```

Now when user clicks on the `CopyScenarioForm.OK` button, I want to validate his entries and if invalid I want to `Exit Sub` from the `OK` button's click handler but when I do that the form still closes out and `DoSomething()` gets executed.  Is there a way to stop this and keep the form alive and only exit if the inputs are valid.  I noticed, if I change the `OK` button's `DialogResult` property to `NONE` instead of `OK` then it doesn't cause it to close. but then how Do I know how the user exited the form to execute `DoSomething()`?.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784167/c-validate-before-leaving-accept-button-event

Comment: @astander, thanks for the answer.  Yes, that is the exact same issue but I like the answer below from Cody Gray.  This seems more appropriate than using a module level switch on the form Cosing event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is that when you have the button's `DialogResult` property set to "OK" in the designer, this value is set every time the OK button is clicked, no matter what. So even when you exit from the event handler early using `Exit Sub`, the calling form sees a `DialogResult` of "OK."

As you discovered, you'll first need to set the button's `DialogResult` property to "None" in the designer, and then handle setting the `DialogResult` property to the correct value manually in your "OK" button's click event handler. For example:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If EntriesAreValid Then
        'Return OK to the calling form
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    Else
        'Show an error message, but keep the form open
        MessageBox.Show("One or more of your entries were invalid.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could leave the `DialogResult` property set to "OK" in the designer, and just override it whenever validation fails by setting it to "None". This probably produces cleaner code—to wit:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not EntriesAreValid Then
        'Show an error message
        MessageBox.Show("One or more of your entries were invalid.")

        'Clear the DialogResult property and keep the form open
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.None
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to keep the form open. Thanks Cody Gray.

Answer (score 0):

Set it from your code if everything checks out.

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
```